# Масштабирование фона в div

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Никак не могу сделать так, чтоб фон `<div>` сжимался при уменьшении разрешения устройства. Нужно решение без медиа-запросов. Чувствую, что решение простое, но никак не могу сообразить, в чем дело.

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
&__wrapper
{
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 675px;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
            justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
            align-items: flex-start;
}

&__right
{
    width: 630px;
    height: 660px;
    margin: auto;
    background: url('../img/dish.png') no-repeat; 
    background-size:auto cover;
}


&__left 
{
    height: 490px;
    width: 409px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: О каком сжимании может идти речь, когда размеры выставленный ???

Comment: Измени единицы измерения в место `px` используй `rem, em, %, vw, vh, vmax, vmin`

Comment: при указании max-width или в % или auto, изображение пропадает почему то. Картинка вообще не ужимается, я уже  много вариантов перепробовал.

Comment: Это что за "конструкция"  `background-size:auto cover;` ?

Comment: Чтоб картинка в див вписывалась с авто размерами. вроде так понял, читал на хтмлбук

Comment: Ты не верно понял... Или `cover` или `auto`

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить: 
1. wrapper width поменял на max-width.
2.

```css
 &__right
 { 
  background-image: url('../img/dish.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 52.5%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
       -o-background-size: contain;
          background-size: contain;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
 }
```